# Create a Folder in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am looking for a way to create folders inside the temp_08 folder.  Temp_08 is the only folder I have write access to, so I need to create the folder INSIDE temp_08.  I was looking to store tables inside this folder, so to more cleanly organize my tables.  What is the best way to perform this function in Redshift?

[image]

Comment: A relational database has no "folders"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a better way to organize tables rather than having hundreds?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift is based on a fork of PostgreSQL. Therefore, it inherits many of the attributes of PostgreSQL.

To arrange your tables into more logical groups, you can use:

- [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_DATABASE.html)
- [`CREATE SCHEMA`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_SCHEMA.html)

From the [Schemas](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Schemas_and_tables.html) documentation:

> A database contains one or more named schemas. Each schema in a database contains tables and other kinds of named objects. By default, a database has a single schema, which is named PUBLIC. You can use schemas to group database objects under a common name. Schemas are **similar to operating system directories**, except that schemas cannot be nested.

Basically, a **Database** is a separate logical grouping. You connect to a specific database when connecting with Amazon Redshift. **Schemas** exist within a Database and a **search path** can determine which one to use (for example, a personal schema first, then a default schema).